# Delete rows with 3 or less characters before asterisk

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in Google Spreadsheets that deletes alls rows with 4 or more numbers.  I would like to modify it to also delete all rows that have 3 or less characters (numbers or otherwise) *before the the asterisk sign*, *.

Here is the script in its current form:

```
function removeRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  var val = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 2).getValues();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var str = row[0].replace(/\D/g, '')//extract the numbers
    var len = str.length // determine lenght of number string
    if(len >=4 ){ //if 4 or more numbers delete
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= val.length-1; i++) {
    var str=val[i][0].split(/[*]/)//split at *
    var numStr = str[0].replace(/\D/g, '');
    var len = numStr.length // determine length of string of first split

    if(len <=3 ){ //if 3 or less, delete
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried till now?

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure how to format this correct.  I'll amend my post above.

Comment: don't paste it here, edit your question.

Comment: @ncoder, just edited the question.

Comment: what is 'val' in your edited snippet?

Comment: `var val = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();`

Comment: okay, so what is the problem you are facing? You should add that too in the question.

Comment: This is the error I get:

Message details
Cannot convert NaN to (class).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `split`ting a cell at the `*` character, you can simply test if the character is present in the cell contents with [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). If there is an `*`, then the integer returned will be 0 or more. A value of 4 or more indicates that 4 or more characters precede the searched character, while a value of 0 - 3 indicates there are 0 - 3 characters before it.

This snippet assumes your sheet data is in an array of arrays named `val` (as is done in the code you have posted above).

```
var colIndex = 0; // Which column in the range should be checked for an *.
for(var i = 0; i < val.length; ++i) {
  var charBefore = String(val[i][colIndex]).indexOf("*");
  if(charBefore < 4 && charBefore >= 0) {
    /*
     * There are 3 or fewer characters preceding the asterisk.
     * Add code in this block to work with i, val, val[i], or val[i][colIndex]
     * for this specific case.
     */
  } else {
    /*
     * There was no asterisk in the cell, or it was preceded by 4+ characters.
     * Add code to this block (or remove the else block entirely, if nothing is to
     * be done with rows / cells that did not meet the specified asterisk criteria.
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this.  I get 'ReferenceError: "val" is not defined.' with your answer.  What should I define 'val' as?

Comment: Actually, 'val' is defined as noted in the code  pasted in my question above.  Yet the script here doesn't remove rows with 3 or fewer characters, though my script continues to remove rows with 4 or more numbers.

Comment: @EdDev your question asked for help deleting rows in which three or fewer characters come before an asterisk. Here your comment just says "3 or fewer characters." Which is it?

Comment: apologies for the imprecision.  The correct requirement is "3 or fewer characters before the asterisk*.

Comment: Hi, @tehhowch, any ideas?

Comment: The code I offer in this answer should already successfully identify the cells that have 3 or fewer characters before an asterisk. The code I gave in my answer does not do anything beyond identify the rows - you are expected to add code to the commented regions.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply.  My problem was about deleting such rows rather than merely identifying them.

Comment: @EdDev apply your existing working code to delete a given row. My answer shows how to find the row(s) to delete. You already know how to delete a row once you have found it.

Comment: @tehhhowch, the error notes that 'val' is not defined.  Here is my test [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eWWuzHbCOHQSF95umgXZn2rMbWpabVecFXFaYBOXy_c/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @EdDev re-read my answer: it is a snippet, whose sole job is to identify rows with an asterisk that have 3 or fewer preceding characters. I expect that you are capable of amending your existing function to use my snippet, giving it a properly instantiated array of sheet data (`val`), and to amend its commented sections to perform your desired task with the identified rows.

Comment: That was utterly unhelpful, but thanks for your time in any case.  Best wishes to you.